# Python file not working in terminal, only in pycharm

Tags: gnome-terminal, python3, pycharm

The program takes a picture and saves it to a directory named images.

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
import cv2
import datetime
filename = datetime.datetime.now()
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, img = cam.read()
if s:
    cv2.imwrite("images/" + str(filename) + ".jpg",img)
```

Running it from pycharm works like a charm (pun not intended) , but running it from terminal fails. The light for the camera flashes, but when I go to my files the file isn't there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This question might be better on Stack Overflow, but a few thoughts. I'm not sure how you are running it, but the first line should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3` if it is a Python 3 script, which it seems like it is (note the space before `python3`). Also, you could try replacing `"images/"` with `"./images/"` and see what happens

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. @cocomac

Comment: A few ideas... (1) replace `cv2.imwrite(...)` with `cv2.imwrite(r"/home/you/testimg.jpg", img)`, and see if the file appears. (2) If it works in PyCharm, the code is probably mostly fine. Specifically, how are you running your code? I would do `python3 myfile.py`

Comment: The first method worked, but I'd had rather it a specific name and directory if that's ok. I use python3 <name>.py @cocomac

Comment: Glad it worked. If it worked, the solution is pretty easy. If you replace the line with `cv2.imwrite("/home/you/" + str(filename) + ".jpg", img)`, it should work.

Comment: Just out of interest... when you run it from a terminal, what directory are you in? Is it the same directory as the script resides or a different directory? Also, are you using the "Run from terminal" menu option from within PyCharm, or a standard xterm? Using the "Run from terminal" option I was unable to reproduce the issue.